# In keycloak 3.3 is it possible to flag Users as invalid or delete them, when they didn't activate after some specific time?

Tags: java, authentication, keycloak

As my Question is already stating:

In my Keycloak application, the User registers and get's an activation Email.

When the user doesn't click the email, he/she stays as a kind of zombie in the database.

My Question is: Is there a mechanism where longevity of a non-activated user can be set so that the user is deleted after some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. 
But you could implement an EventListener SPI detecting when a user is disabled. Then the SPI could start a scheduled Task in order to delete the user after a certain time.
The Task should be aborted, if the user is enabled again.
There is a Timer SPI for Scheduled Tasks, as well, but I never used this SPI by myself. 
The 'Register' event may also be a good hook for adding such Task functionality.

Comment: Is there a mechanism in keycloak for disable the user? Like: If the user is not verified by mail for one day, he gets disabled.

Comment: That sound a lot like the 'required actions' field in the admin console

Comment: In the admin console. Realm-Settings -> Login -> verify Email may be the option you look for

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I already activated --> verifyEmail. I don't think keycloak has an mechanism to physically delete "not-activated-users" after some time. And I think there needs to be a SPI implemented.